# How do I add metadata to wordpress so it's pulled when adding a Facebook link?

Tags: facebook, wordpress, metadata

I have a wordpress site and I'm creating a facebook page to announce new articles added in the blog.
But I'm having two problems:

1. Whenever I add a link to the main site, I get a default text describing the site, probably from some automatic post. I've deleted the default post and the page that are created automatically with each wordpress installation, so I'm not sure where it's pulling this from, and I'd like to add my own text describing the blog: http://snag.gy/0AZaw.jpg
   Notice that it's not pulling any thumbnail images from the site either. It's just a plain text link, very dull and boring.
2. Also, I have featured images for each one of my posts, but when I link to a specific post within facebook, I don't get an image thumbnail. I'd like to have the featured image to be pulled or either add a hidden image somehow, so it's pulled from Facebook but it's not displayed in the actual blogpost.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to include Facebook Open Graphic tags to help Facebook out with the information that gets displayed. Here's the documentation from Facebook to explain their use of Open Graph:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/#selfhosted-creating

If you're a theme developer, you can add these into your theme yourself by pasting something like this in your blog header.php file:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php wp_title(); ?>"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url') . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content=""/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="The Hired Guns"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content=""/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>" />
```

That said, I highly recommend using an great plugin called SEO by Yoast for doing this for you:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/

This will allow you to fine tune the sharing image, description, etc for each page and post.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I installed the plugin and went post by post adding in "Social" a description and image to be displayed. However, when I try to post a link to Facebook, only the description shows up. No thumbnail at all. I also tried the solution given here, with no luck: http://www.efrennolasco.com/wordpress-how-to-fix-no-featured-thumbnail-issue-on-facebook-share/
I changed the theme to see if mine was interfering somehow, but it didn't help either...
This is my blog (it's in Spanish, but just take any link to a post from the front page to see what I mean) http://ladoderecho.co.nf/

Comment: Everything is set up  correctly with your open graph tags now, so that's cool. The problem is with the image your using:
..wp-content/uploads/2014/03/logold.png
Browsing to that image leads to a 500 error from the web server. The image you use needs to be accessible by Facebook, so troubleshoot why and it should start appearing. Your host should be able to help you out with this.

Comment: Thanks :)
I changed the image to an external image url (snag.gy), but still I don't get a thumbnail. I also don't get my description when the root site is linked ("Hello world!Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start blogging!PatriciaMarch 19, 2014UncategorizedPermalink").
For individual blogposts, I do get the description I enter, but no image shows up as a thumbnail (I set up an image for SEO, and my posts also have a featured image).
Would my host be the culprit of all this?